# User authentication using POE::Component::Client::HTTP

Tags: perl, asynchronous, cpan, poe

I am trying to find a module in perl poe which can do user authentication while making a `HTTP request`.

HTTP request should be non-blocking

or

How should I use `poe::component::client:http` to do user authentication by providing username , password details?

Comment: Is the question if you can use POE with (Basic Authentication)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication]?

Comment: yes i would like to use poe::component::client:http compenent with basic authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) object to [POE::Component::Client::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Component::Client::HTTP). Basic Auth is solved with a header, and can be sent as a header:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use MIME::Base64;
 use HTTP::Request;

 my $username = 'username';
 my $password = 'password';
 my $auth = 'Basic ' . MIME::Base64::encode($username . ':' . $password);

 my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.example/',
    [Authorization => $auth]);
```

And then just pass the `$request` to `$poe_kernel->post` as in the documentation.

Comment: i like the same authentication as like we do in  lwp agent , which includes host-port address, realm string , username and password.

Comment: @user3540276: Yes. Then you need to find a component that does that, or implement it yourself.

Comment: i want digest auth system to be injected in my request headers

Comment: Is there a way so that i can inject lwp agent in poe::component::client:http

Comment: No. There is no easy way of using LWP::UserAgent. You could look at https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/libwww-perl-6.15/lib/LWP/Authen/Digest.pm to see how LWP implements Digest.